# how to input data and print it via console.log button in vue3

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Hi im understanding vue structure before i was using react
my question is how to implement this react code to vue 3?

```
function App() ={
const [print, setPrint] = useState('')
return(
 <div>
   <input type='text' placeholder='input text her' 
   value={print} onChange={e=>setPrint(e.target.value)/>
   <button onClick={()=>console.log(print)}> click me </button>

 </div>

}
```

and could you guys please explain me the structure of vue thant react ?

note: i am building a POST request in vue so that is why i need to store this and empty string variables

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `v-model` to make a two way data bind for input value and use `@click` event to call a funciton that print the input value like this below,

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const msg = ref("");  
  
const fnCall = (event) =>{
  //event is the native DOM even
  console.log(event);
  console.log(msg.value);
}
</script>

<template>
  <input v-model="msg" placeholder='input text her' >
  <button @click="fnCall">Click</button>
</template>
```